# How to make e-mail invisible on Stack Exchange profile

Tags: support, profile-page, email

Is there a way to make my e-mail non-visible in my Stack Exchange profile?

Comment: If your email is used to generate your gravatar, then it's probably public. It's easy to guess a few billion potential email addresses. One of them might match your gravatar hash.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your email is only shown to you and diamond moderators, not to everyone. Recent change requires diamond moderators to click on a link to show the email, it is not visible until then.

Here's how I see your profile (as a 10k user, even):

[image]

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the answer and the image!

Comment: @Mark is the clicking on a link a safety measure? I mean so later they can know if a Mod actually looked at the email? or nothing like that?

Comment: @Trufa: I wish I could say -- that's an edit from @Diago.

Comment: @Mark, sorry missed the missing ♦! :) Thanks you!

Comment: @Diago I don't know if you'll get notified but I still like to know,  is the clicking on a link a safety measure? I mean so later they can know if a Mod actually looked at the email? or nothing like that?

Comment: @trufa I am assuming it is a safety measure. Keep in mind each site has a handful of mods and with the new messaging system we hardly need the email address of users. Honestly, I can't think of a single reason for you to be concerned about it, and if you are, just take it out completely. It's not a required field.

Comment: @Diago I'm not worried I'm just curious. Thanks for the reply, BTW (again just curious) did you actually got notified for editing the answer o you just saw my comment?

Answer (score 2):

Only you (and the people who run SO - including moderators) can see your email address.  No need to worry about the spammers getting it.  :)

Comment: Did you mean to comment on the other answer ( http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77453/how-to-make-email-invisible-in-stackoverflow/77454#77454 )?  :)

Comment: Did you mean to start your answering comment with @Letseatlunch? :D

Comment: @bel: Did you mean to start your comment with @cHao?  :)  OK, let's stop.  Just cause this is meta doesn't mean we have to be...  :)

Comment: Ok, so +1 because you didn't brag (yet) :D

Comment: He-hey!! I won points for the edit :) first timer for me :)