# Do people see my e-mail in my various SE profiles?

Tags: support, email, privacy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make e-mail invisible on Stack Exchange profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77453/how-to-make-e-mail-invisible-on-stack-exchange-profile)

I have used my e-mail to sign up for Stack Exchange. Each SE site in which I participate has created its own profile.  Do people see my e-mail address in my general profile?  Do people see my e-mail in each of the sub-profiles?

If so, how do I change that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only [diamond moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/who-are-the-diamond-moderators-and-what-is-their-role) and Stack Exchange employees can see your email, no one else. 
When it comes to diamond moderators, we can only see your e-mail on the sites we are moderators on - you can use different e-mails per account if you want.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that we don't see your email in plain view just by opening your profile.  We have to click a link to see it, so we're discouraged from looking up people's email unless we really need it.