# What is the profile email address used for?

Tags: support, profile-page

The notification emails go to the email address set in "preferences".

The email address in each sites' user profile is separate from this. What are the user profile email addresses used for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The email address on your profile page is only ever used to identify your account when you contact the Stack Exchange team, mainly for account recovery purposes. [More from Kevin.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/170331)

They can also be used to create a hash for [Gravatar](http://gravatar.com), if you choose to use that rather than an uploaded profile picture.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it was also used for gravatar? Also, given what Kevin says, are the only implications of using a fake address there a difficulty when contacting support?

Comment: @Jason - if you use a fake address and lose your login details, you pretty much lose that account.

Comment: @Oded I'm confused. My login is the same for all my network accounts, so I can't quite reconcile profile-email-based recovery with imagining what would happen if I had a different profile email address for every profile. Also, wouldn't that not be an issue if I e.g. use the Google provider to log in? I've never entered a password or anything on SE itself to log in.

Comment: @JasonC Think about someone who only used MyOpenID for their accounts and provided a fake email on their profile. Or maybe someone decided they no longer liked Yahoo and deleted their account there. There are plenty of ways where you could lose your ability to login to your account here, and that email address is your ticket to retrieving your account again.

Comment: @animuson I see, thanks. Ok, then updating question in first comment: Given that I use Google to log in and currently have no plans to shut down my Google account, in my current state does that mean there are no implications of using a fake address, for me personally, since I would never require an SE account recovery?

Comment: @JasonC That depends on how you contact them. If you link to your account on the site, then you would have absolutely no difficult whatsoever. If you emailed them from some random email address that's not connected to any account on Stack Exchange and you provide no information as to what site you're using or what name is on your account, you'd run into some trouble communicating. So no, I wouldn't say there are any implications for you, personally. I use a fake email on one of my accounts somewhere.

Comment: @animuson Thanks. Are the profile emails used for gravatars?

Comment: @JasonC Yes, if you choose to use Gravatar versus a profile picture.

Comment: @animuson Perfect, thanks. If you add that to the answer plus confirmation that they *aren't* sent to gravatar if you're using a profile picture I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: @Jason - nothing is sent to gravatar, except for a request for the image URL (if you chose to use gravatar, that is). If you want to use a gravatar, the way gravatar works is by an MD5 hash of the email - that's the gravatar address. We also offer an "identicon", where we salt the email address prior to hashing.

Comment: @Oded Thanks; the hashes are more what I meant. Glad you guys offer the salted version, and thank you for that. For gravatar, in general, I try not to use the same email address on any two sites, mostly out of rebellion against that type of potential data mining, moreso than explicit privacy concerns. That was part of the (unmentioned) reason for my initial question in the first place. Incidentally, since I'm not using the gravatars, after this answer I just went ahead an put a real email address in the profile.